# .asp net mvc core 2 DI'ed service with constructor parameters.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a service, added here

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {          
        services.AddScoped<IDNCoreBlobAgent, DNCoreBlobAgent>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

However I designed it with several constructor parameters, to separate out my credentials, blob container name, as well the possibility of a specific policy.

```
 public DNCoreBlobAgent(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, string 
     containerName, string policyName = null)
    {
        //Does stuff with those parameters
    }
```

I want to pass those parameters at the the controller action level or somewhere other than ConfigureServices. The action would look something like:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ProjectReport( [FromServices] 
     IDNCoreBlobAgent blob, int projectid)
    {
        Project project = _data.GetProject(projectid);
        string html = GetHtml();            
        var link = blob.SendHtmlBlob(html);            
        return PartialView("_ProjectReport", link);
    }
```

Is this the wrong way to go about this? Should I not make this a service?

Comment: How about storing those in `appsettings.json` ?

Comment: No ,for so many reasons. For one, I'd like the ability to call different containers in the same app, or use default policy in one call or pass a policy in another.

Comment: Where do the values for `containerName` and `policyName` come from? There are really only a few ways this could go - if they are *application-wide configuration values*, then they go in the constructor. If they are *runtime values*, then they should be passed as parameters to the `SendHtmlBlob` method. If *other*, then you have an application design problem that can be solved with design patterns, not a DI problem.

Comment: They are runtime, so yes, much like Tomas Smagurauskas suggested, they will now be passed into the method. I don't like it as much because it means every method in my service has to have that as a parameter, but it could be worse.

Answer (score 1):

This goes against the dependency injection idea. Dependency injection provides works based on inversion of control, thus all of the components are created from lowest level to highest level in that order. Therefore, theoretically, at the time your service is being created, the controller doesn't exist yet, so it is impossible that it could pass any parameters to the service's constructor.

Intended design is indeed to pass these parameters at action level, rather than at the constructor level.

Comment: So I should pass those as parameters to the service's  method like blob.SendHtmlBlob(storageAccount, containerName,  policyName , html)?

Comment: @greedyLump yes, that's pretty much the only non-hacky way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific of the task but if you didn't want to put settings in `appsettings.json` you'd implement fabric pattern with `IDNCoreBlobAgent` main interface and `DNCoreBlobAgent`, `DNCoreBlobAgent1` and etc. elements.

(Added)

```
IParameterFabric concreteParameters = ParameterFabricHelper.GetParameters(CloudStorageAccount storageAccount, string 
         containerName, string policyName = null);
```

In `GetParameters` will be conditions which concrete implementation you need.

Comment: The credentials, maybe (more realistically in secrets.json). But you propose a whole family of concrete implementations? and how do i specify in a controller or controller action which i want called?

Comment: Take a look in answer, I've amended it.